# How to remove duplicate rows in matrix in eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am trying to apply a uniqueness to MatrixXi in eigen. But I didn't find any workaround or api in eigen library.

My goal is :

```
MatrixXi mat = {{1,2,3},{2,3,1},{4,5,6},{1,2,3},{1,3,2},{4,3,5},{4,5,6}}
```

After apply uniqueness, I need

```
auto mat_unique = {{1,2,3},{1,3,2},{2,3,1},{4,3,5},{4,5,6}}
```

I need to apply uniqueness for bigger matrix.

Is there any workaround or APi in eigen?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution to my problem. Here is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693909/sort-eigen-matrix-column-values-by-ascending-order-of-column-1-values)

But the solution is only for sorting, not for removing duplicates. So one needs to add one more line of code in the middle.

```
void eigen_sort_unique_rows_by_head(Eigen::MatrixXi& A_nx3)
{
    std::vector<Eigen::VectorXi> vec;
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < A_nx3.rows(); ++i)
        vec.push_back(A_nx3.row(i));

    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](Eigen::VectorXi const& t1, Eigen::VectorXi const& t2){ return t1(0) < t2(0); } );

    auto it = std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    vec.resize(std::distance(vec.begin(),it));

    A_nx3.resize(vec.size(),3);
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
        A_nx3.row(i) = vec[i];
};
```