# `std::stable_sort` gives wrong results when `std::execution::par`

Tags: c++, eigen, stable-sort

I wrote simple algorithm for sorting rows in Eigen matrix.
This should do the same as [Matlab's sortrows](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.sortrows.html) function:

```cpp
template <typename D>
void _sort(
    const D &M,
    Eigen::VectorX<ptrdiff_t>& idx,
    std::function<bool(ptrdiff_t, ptrdiff_t)> cmp_fun)
{
  // initialize original index locations
  idx = Eigen::ArrayX<ptrdiff_t>::LinSpaced(
        M.rows(), 0, M.rows()-1);

  std::stable_sort(std::execution::par, idx.begin(), idx.end(), cmp_fun);
}


/// \brief sort_rows  sorts the rows of a matrix in ascending order
/// based on the elements in the first column. When the first column
/// contains repeated elements, sortrows sorts according to the values
/// in the next column and repeats this behavior for succeeding equal values.
/// M_sorted = M(ind, Eigen::all)
/// \param M
/// \return ind
template <typename D>
Eigen::VectorX<ptrdiff_t> sort_rows(const Eigen::DenseBase<D> &M){

  // initialize original index locations
  Eigen::VectorX<ptrdiff_t> idx;

  ptrdiff_t col = 0;

  std::function<bool(ptrdiff_t, ptrdiff_t)> cmp_fun;
  cmp_fun = [&M, &col, &cmp_fun](
      const ptrdiff_t& row1,
      const ptrdiff_t& row2)->bool
  {
    if (M(row1, col) < M(row2, col)){
      col = 0;
      return true;
    }

    if (M(row1, col) > M(row2, col)){
      col = 0;
      return false;
    }

    // only 'M(row1, col) == M(row2, col)'  option is left
    // it will return 'true' only if this is the last column
    // i.e. all other columns at these rows are also equal
    if (col == M.cols()-1){
      if (M(row1, col) == M(row2, col)){
        col = 0;
        return true;
      }

      col = 0;
      return false;
    }

    col++;
    return cmp_fun(row1, row2);
  };

  _sort(M.derived(), idx, cmp_fun);

  return idx;
}
```

If I set `std::execution::par` i get wrong result like in the picture:
[image]

With `std::execution::seq` and the same data the graph non-decreasingly grows in steps (correct result).

What should I know about execution policy to avoid such situations?

**EDIT: my implementation for `sort_rows` that now works with** `std::execution::par` and doesn't use recursion anymore:

```cpp
template <typename D>
void _sort(
    const D &M,
    Eigen::VectorX<ptrdiff_t>& idx,
    std::function<bool(ptrdiff_t, ptrdiff_t)> cmp_fun)
{
  // initialize original index locations
  idx = Eigen::ArrayX<ptrdiff_t>::LinSpaced(
        M.rows(), 0, M.rows()-1);

  std::stable_sort(std::execution::par, idx.begin(), idx.end(), cmp_fun);
}


/// \brief sort_rows  sorts the rows of a matrix in ascending order
/// based on the elements in the first column. When the first column
/// contains repeated elements, sortrows sorts according to the values
/// in the next column and repeats this behavior for succeeding equal values.
/// M_sorted = M(ind, Eigen::all)
/// \param M
/// \return ind
template <typename D>
Eigen::VectorX<ptrdiff_t> sort_rows(const Eigen::DenseBase<D> &M){

  // initialize original index locations
  Eigen::VectorX<ptrdiff_t> idx;

  std::function<bool(ptrdiff_t, ptrdiff_t)> cmp_fun;
  cmp_fun = [&M](
      const ptrdiff_t& row1,
      const ptrdiff_t& row2)->bool
  {
    ptrdiff_t N = M.cols()-1;
    for (ptrdiff_t col = 0; col < N; col++){
      if (M(row1, col) < M(row2, col))
        return true;

      if (M(row1, col) > M(row2, col))
        return false;
    }

    // notice the operator is '<=' as it is the last column check
    // i.e. when all other columns are equal at these rows
    if (M(row1, Eigen::last) <= M(row2, Eigen::last))
      return true;

    return false;
  };

  _sort(M.derived(), idx, cmp_fun);

  return idx;
}
```

Comment: You have a data-race. Your comparison function accesses and *modifies* `col` without any kind of synchronization.

Comment: The race condition is definitely the main issue here. However, you should also note that using an ```std::function``` wrapper for the comparison is highly inefficient

Comment: I'm also not sure it follows [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings). And the whole recursion part seems dubious to me.

Comment: Your posted code uses `sort` not `stable_sort` which your question title is asking about..

Comment: thank you for comments.
I should google `data-race`, that make sense.
Also I slightly modified the question to use `std::stable_sort` instead of `std::sort`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my implementation of rowsort. I find the documentation of rowsort somewhat confusing. I work under the assumption that it is just a lexicographical sort.

Note that your code can probably be fixed just by making a col variable local to your lambda instead of having it as a shared reference.

```
template<class Derived>
void rowsort(Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& mat)
{
    using PermutationMatrix = 
          Eigen::PermutationMatrix<Derived::RowsAtCompileTime>;
    PermutationMatrix permut;
    permut.setIdentity(mat.rows());
    auto& indices = permut.indices();
    std::stable_sort(std::execution::par, indices.begin(), indices.end(),
          [&mat](Eigen::Index left, Eigen::Index right) noexcept -> bool          
          {
              const auto& leftrow = mat.row(left);
              const auto& rightrow = mat.row(right);
              for(Eigen::Index col = 0, cols = mat.cols();
                    col < cols; ++col) {
                  const auto& leftval = leftrow[col];
                  const auto& rightval = rightrow[col];
                  if(leftval < rightval)
                      return true;
                  if(leftval > rightval)
                      break;
              }
              return false;
          });
    mat = permut.inverse() * mat;
}
```

Notes:

- There might be a clever way to avoid inverting the permutation.
- It's a bit annoying that applying the permutation is only defined for MatrixBase, not DenseBase
- stable sort isn't necessary for this. I assume you have an external reason for using it
- The function should probably take the matrix as a const reference so that it can be called seamlessly with `block()` expressions and then cast away the const. I didn't put it in to avoid making the code ugly and confusing. Refer to the relevant chapter in the documentation on [passing Eigen types to functions](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html)

Comment: Thank you for your time!
I edited the question and posted my solution there. 
You use few Eigen methods that I haven't worked with before. Do you use premutation to make the sorting run faster or there are some other reasons?
Yes, probably I should better use `std::sort` instead but I'm not sure yet whether that will be critical to me in the fututre. And I don't know yet how much of perfomance I loose when I use `std::stable_sort` instead of `std::sort`.
Ad I forget to tell that the matrix that I may work with may be big enough say `[1e8, 3]`

Comment: @Kerim I use the permutation to apply the indices to the sorted matrix in the end. Your code doesn't show that part. I just figured that Eigen is probably better at doing that part than me hand-crafting the same thing. I'm not sure why your code checks for less-equal in the last column. Note that the comparison implements "less", not "less-equal". Also, again ```std::function``` will kill your performance without any benefit.

Comment: I'm also interested in indexes of that sorted array so that I could do: `v_sorted = v(ind)`. This `ind` array may be used for retrieving data from other array `v_other` that is somehow related to `v` and usually have the same number of rows as `v`. Thus my algorithm returns indexes `ind` that I use for further computations.

Comment: @Kerim the ```ind``` array should be ```permut.indices()``` after sorting (not the inverse).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this almost out-of-the-box using Eigen's iterator interface and `std::lexicographical_compare`:

```
std::sort(A.rowwise().begin(), A.rowwise().end(),
  [](auto const& r1, auto const& r2){
     return std::lexicographical_compare(r1.begin(), r1.end(), r2.begin(), r2.end());});
```

Unfortunately, you first need to declare an `Eigen::swap` function for this to work (this may get fixed in later versions -- see also this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71556445/):

```
namespace Eigen {
    template<class T>
    void swap(T&& a, T&& b){
        a.swap(b);
    }
}
```

And see this for a working example:
https://godbolt.org/z/7P1hYTn65

Your initial plan of sorting an index-list and doing just one permutation could actually be faster for large rows (I did not benchmark this).

Comment: Thank you very much! I use Eigen 3.4 so it is worth to try ( I deleted previous comment as it was unrelated)
Also I didn't know that there is a built in comparators like `std::lexicographical_compare`

Comment: Really nice solution. I did some benchmarks, your version vs. mine with the dimensions given by @Kerim (1e8, 3): lexicographical_compare is slightly slower than mine (I guess because it handles different lengths for both ranges). For ```MatrixXf``` mine is significantly faster (34s vs 9s), for ```MatrixX3f``` yours is a bit faster (6s vs 8s). Seems like unrolling the rowwise swap is important

Comment: @Homer512 have you compared it using `std::execution::par` or `std::execution::seq`?

Comment: @Kerim with and without par (par helps a lot with this size). Also stable vs. normal sort. stable is (unsurprisingly) a bit slower, but not much.

Comment: @Homer512 I assume for large enough rows, the cost of copying/swapping rows is significantly more expensive than one level of redirection during the comparison. Especially, swapping rows in a column-major matrix is very inefficient. The difference should be more significant when sorting a row-major matrix with few elements (ideally also a multiple of a packet-size).

Comment: For reference, here is my benchmark code https://godbolt.org/z/9rdos5f3Y. Sorting columns is faster but the biggest factor is still switching to MatrixX3f or Matrix3Xf, even if the MatrixXf had the same size at runtime. Very weird in my opinion.